# How to extract values from a JSON field with Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

When I run mongdob query I got this json results in a column.
Column name is "{} user"

```
{"email": "mail1@mail.com"}
{"email": "mail6@mail6.com", "name": "name1"}
{"email": "mail2@mail.com"}
{"email": "mail7@mail7.com", "name": "name2"}
{"email": "mail3@mail.com"}
{"email": "mail5@mail8.com", "name": "name3"}
{"email": "mail4@mail.com"}
{"email": "mail5@mail9.com", "name": "name4"}
```

However I need to extract email and name from this JSON into different columns like
"email", "name"

How can I do this with Mongodb?

Output

[image]

Query

```
db.requests.find(
{
"$and" : [

{"updatedAt": { $gt: ISODate("2020-04-19") }},
{"updatedAt": { $lt: ISODate("2020-05-08") }},
]
},
    {
        "user.email" : 1.0,
        "user.name" : 1.0,
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you add a simple of the required output please?

Comment: Added please check @ThomasBormans

Comment: What do you mean "extract email and name from this JSON into different columns"? What are inputs?

Comment: I think this is just "a render issue" or "misconception about MongoDB". Mongo returns JSON objects, not data in columns like SQL.

Comment: Also, how how did the `mail2` in 4th row becomes "name2`?

Comment: @ThomasBormans I was expecting something like SQL as you said. So I have to deal with it with it in the backend?

Comment: You can extract that for example: https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-export-csv-json-sql-bson/

Comment: @chakwok was just a mistake corrected now

Comment: @briba I am also using studio3t maybe it is theonly way I will check.

Comment: could you please show us the mongodb query? or what language are you using here?

Comment: @lfaruki added please check

Comment: @SNaRe : You need to provide actual result & sample docs & ask for desired output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also export the results to a csv for example:

```
mongoexport --host localhost --db dbname --collection name --csv --out text.csv --fields firstName,middleName,lastName
```

Or also:

```
print("name,email");
db.YOUR_COLLECTION.find().forEach(function(rec){
  print(rec.name+","+rec.email);
});
```

Comment: I couldn't also apply your solution but extracting with https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-export-csv-json-sql-bson/ what easiest